# Error in SaveSWF {animation}

Tags: r, animation

I'm trying to use the code published on http://yihui.name/en/2009/12/merry-christmas-using-r/ but I end up with the following error:

> In saveSWF({ : the executablepng2swf.exedoes not exist!

What can I do about it? Should I install the SWFTolls?

Answer (score 0):

That means saveSWF() cannot find SWF Tools, and you should either put 
it on PATH or provide its installation path. See `swftools` in 
?animation::saveSWF

from http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Warning-Message-In-saveSWF-the-executablepng2swf-exedoes-not-exist-td4690755.html